# How to post/ update data to PHP in Angular JS 1.6.9?

Tags: php, html, angularjs

My existing project ran on Angular JS 1.5.7, all the functionalities were working properly, but when I changed the version to 1.6.9, all the functionalities stopped working, then I had to replace the .success with .then, however, the post and update function isn't working.
Angular JS 1.5

```
    $http.post(
        "insert.php", {
            'name': $scope.name,
            'email': $scope.email,
            'age': $scope.age,
            'buttonName': $scope.buttonName,
            'id': $scope.id
        }
    ).success(function (data) { //this function works on Angular JS 1.4.8
        alert(data);
        $scope.name = null;
        $scope.email = null;
        $scope.age = null;
        $scope.buttonName = "Insert";
        $scope.show_data();
    });
    //alert('Data inserted');
    $scope.IsVisible = $scope.IsVisible = true;
    $scope.response_msg = "Data Inserted";
}
```

I tried to replace the .success with .then didn't work.
PHP code:

```
if(empty($info)){
}
else{
$emp_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$info->id);
$emp_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$info->name);
$emp_email=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$info->email);
$emp_age=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$info->age);
$button_name=$info->buttonName;
```

Comment: `$http`'s deprecated custom callback methods - `success()` and `error()` - have been removed.
You can use the standard `then()`/`catch()` promise methods instead, **but note that the method
signatures and return values are different.**

Answer (score 0):

Try add catch function after then function and print error in catch function to console.